# Splash Qt for playbook

Tags: splash-screen, blackberry-playbook

I'm developing on QtCreator for Playbook. In bar-descriptor.xml I set the path for splash as follow:

```
<asset path="splash.jpg">splash.jpg</asset>
```

For setting splash screen I tried:

```
<splashscreen>splash.jpg</splashscreen>
<splashScreen>splash.jpg</splashScreen>
<splash>splash.jpg</splash>
<splashscreen><image>splash.jpg</image></splashscreen>
<splashScreen><image>splash.jpg</image></splashScreen>
<splash><image>splash.jpg</image></splash>
```

But splash screen appears as default black image with BB logo. Someone knows how change it?

Anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt requires landscape and portrait splash image. So, in my case, landscape and portrait are the same and the way for edit this is like follow:

```
<splashscreen>splash.jpg:splash.jpg</splashscreen>
```

In other cases, when exists both images, the way for edit this is like follow:

```
<splashscreen>splash_landscape.jpg:splash_portrait.jpg</splashscreen>
```